# Equivalent of <f:ajax render="@form" />

Tags: ajax, jsf

Recently I started using prettyfaces with my web application which uses jsf1.x. While testing I realized that action methods for h:commandButton and h:commandLink is not getting called. Upon searching on the net, I found a link on this site where some suggested to use `<f:ajax render="@form" />` it should be ok. Since `f:ajax` is available in JSF2.x, so I was thinking how can I find the equivalent of `<f:ajax render="@form" />` in Jsf1.x

Any help be greatly appreciated as I am completely stuck due to this.

Thanks,
Neeraj

Comment: You could consider using richfaces 3.3 `<a4j:ajax`...

Comment: Ajax appears to be least of your problems. You should be more interested in troubleshooting why your command components are not firing. An "equivalent of `<f:ajax render="@form"/>`" is very ambiguous and will most likely not do much. Post your code here and describe the concrete use problem

Comment: If a normal command button does already not work, `<f:ajax>` won't help anything, simply because it requires a working command button. I recommend to take a step back and fix the button invocation failure. Here's a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183

Answer (score 0):

There is something seriously wrong if the actions of the `h:commandButton` and `h:commandLink` are not being called anymore. Maybe it's something easy like failed validation, which cancels the call of the `action` (try `immediate="true" in your button/links`). If it's not, then you should try to find and fix what causes this instead of switching to Ajax functionality.

As already pointed out, you may use `a4j` which is delivered with RichFaces 3 and works also with JSF 1.

*BUT* you cannot throw away this basic functionality. Using Ajax only you will run into a lot of problems later on. `a4j:ajax` might be the equivalent of `f:ajax`, but it's certainly not equivalent to the standard post-`action` functionality.

One common usecase would be a PDF to be displayed. This isn't possible with an Ajax partial-update.